# Javascript object when setting property all properties with same name are set

Tags: javascript, node.js, object

I've only recently started working with javascript and NodeJs.
I'm facing a simple problem that I am finding difficult to find answers to online.
I'm initialising an object holding a number of products each product then has a price and availability. When I try and set the price of one product, it sets the price of all the products rather than just the one i wanted to set. What am I doing wrong?

```js
var ProdStruct = {
  'price' : 0,
  'available' : 0,
};
var Prods = {
  '1' : ProdStruct,
  '2' : ProdStruct,
  '3' : ProdStruct,
  '4' : ProdStruct,
  '5' : ProdStruct,
  '6' : ProdStruct,
  '6' : ProdStruct,
  '7' : ProdStruct
};
Prods['6']['price'] = 99;
console.log(Prods);
```

The Output:

```js
{ '1': { price: 99, available: 0 },
  '2': { price: 99, available: 0 },
  '3': { price: 99, available: 0 },
  '4': { price: 99, available: 0 },
  '5': { price: 99, available: 0 },
  '6': { price: 99, available: 0 },
  '7': { price: 99, available: 0 } }
```

Answer (score 6):

You have only **one** `ProdStruct` object, which you're *referring to* seven times. That is, you have something like this in memory:

```
                                        +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
ProdStruct−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+−+−+−+−+−+−+−−>|   (object)   |
                       / / / / / / /    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
                       | | | | | | |    | price: 0     |
                       | | | | | | |    | available: 0 |
                       | | | | | | |    +−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
         +−−−−−−−−−−+  | | | | | | |
Prods−−−>| (object) |  | | | | | | |
         +−−−−−−−−−−+  | | | | | | |
         | 1        |−−+ | | | | | |
         | 2        |−−−−+ | | | | |
         | 3        |−−−−−−+ | | | |
         | 4        |−−−−−−−−+ | | |
         | 5        |−−−−−−−−−−+ | |
         | 6        |−−−−−−−−−−−−+ |
         | 7        |−−−−−−−−−−−−−−+
         +−−−−−−−−−−+
```

Modifying the state of that one object (changing `price`) modifies its state; doesn't matter which of the seven references you use to get to it to make the change or to look at the result, it's just one object.

You'd need to make a *copy* of the object to get the result you expect. One way is to use `Object.assign`:

```js
var ProdStruct = {
  'price' : 0,
  'available' : 0,
};
var Prods = {
  '1' : Object.assign({}, ProdStruct),
  '2' : Object.assign({}, ProdStruct),
  '3' : Object.assign({}, ProdStruct),
  '4' : Object.assign({}, ProdStruct),
  '5' : Object.assign({}, ProdStruct),
  '6' : Object.assign({}, ProdStruct),
  '6' : Object.assign({}, ProdStruct),
  '7' : Object.assign({}, ProdStruct)
};
Prods['6']['price'] = 99;
console.log(Prods);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

...but I think in your case I'd probably just have a constructor function:

```js
function Prod() {
  this.price = 0;
  this.available = 0;
}
var Prods = {
  '1' : new Prod(),
  '2' : new Prod(),
  '3' : new Prod(),
  '4' : new Prod(),
  '5' : new Prod(),
  '6' : new Prod(),
  '6' : new Prod(),
  '7' : new Prod()
};
Prods['6']['price'] = 99;
console.log(Prods);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

As [Rick mentioned in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50999351/javascript-object-when-setting-property-all-properties-with-same-name-are-set/50999383?noredirect=1#comment88992818_50999383), you could have that constructor accept parameters:

```
function Prod(price, available) {
  this.price = price || 0;
  this.available = available || 0;
}
```

In that, if you don't provide `price` or `available`, it will have the value `undefined`, and that code uses the common idiom `something || default` to use `0` instead of `undefined`, making use of what I call the [curiously powerful `||` operator](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2008/02/javascripts-curiously-powerful-or.html?m=1). (Beware of doing this when it's valid for `something` to be a *falsy** value.)

In ES2015 and later, you could do those defaults in the parameter list:

```
function Prod(price = 0, available = 0) {
  this.price = price;
  this.available = available;
}
```

The defaults will get applied if you don't provide arguments for those parameters (or if you explicitly provide `undefined` for them).

* "falsy" - In JavaScript, a value that coerces to `false` when used as a boolean is *falsy*. The falsy values are `0`, `""`, `null`, `undefined`, `NaN`, and of course, `false`. All other values are *truthy*.

---

A couple of side-notes:

1. In JavaScript, the overwhelming convention is to only use initially-capped names for constructor functions, not for variables referring to other things. So `prodStruct` and `prods`.
2. A series of things like your `Prods` would probably be better as an array (`[]`), rather than an object with number-named properties.
3. The quotes around a property name in an object initializer are only required if the name isn't a valid identifier or a valid integer. All of your property names are, so you could leave them off.
4. Although `Prods['6']['price']` works, it's more simply and idiomatically written `prods[6].price`.

Comment: op should have taken 20 properties ... ;-)

Comment: @NinaScholz - LOL, I would have used an `...` :-)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, so to solve this would I have to manually setup each product?

Comment: @Mr_James - I added to the answer. I posted, then realized I hadn't said what to do instead. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Thanks, it all makes sense! :)

Comment: No, you could change TJ's function a bit to allow you to create a product easily enough. function Prod(price, available) { this.price = price, this.available = available} then to create a new product you could do new Prod( 56.5, 500)

Comment: @Mr_James - Updated the answer a bit more to fold in Rick's excellent point above.

Comment: I would prefer `{...ProductStruct}` over Object.assign, but still great answer as always :)

Comment: Just a plain vanilla example of TJ's last edit. http://jsfiddle.net/tjv8d6ar/24 Of course you'd have to handle the empty inputs otherwise the 0 defaults get overwritten with nothing.

Comment: @JonasW. - Yeah, it's more expressive. Property spread is still brand-new, though (ES2018), and I figured we were dealing with a beginner. :-)